# Android SearchView suggestions appear above the widget

Tags: android, searchview

I'm using SearchView away from the actionbar, as a view in the activity main layout. 
The problem is that suggestions appear above the widget like this

[image]

How to display it below the widget? Am I missing some configuration?

Answer (score 2):

> How to display it below the widget? Am I missing some configuration?

This is the normal behavior of the `AutoCompleteTextView`, if there is no free space available underneath it. So unless you don't shift it to the top of the layout you can't. The suggestion box will never overlap the keyboard.